# no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='IDToken1']"}

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am giving correct XPath. there is only one matching node too. but it still gives me issue.
I am using TestNG

My Code is :

```
driver.navigate().to("http://uk.support.tomtom.com/app/questions/extended_warranty");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='IDToken1']")).sendKeys("myemailaddress");
```

HTML is :

```
<input id="IDToken1" class="form-control" name="IDToken1" value="" data-validation="text" data-required="true" onkeydown="enableSubmit();" onchange="enableSubmit();" onkeyup="enableSubmit();" onmouseup="enableSubmit();" placeholder="example@tomtom.com" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Check if element located inside an `<iframe>`

Comment: @Andersson No there is no iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just logged into the website : http://uk.support.tomtom.com/app/questions/extended_warranty

and I found that the xpath you are providing seems to be incorrect. Use the xpath as shown below , I found that to be the xpath of the email address field. Give it a shot

```
 //*[@id='rn_LoginFormRedirect_3_Username']
```

And my suggestion would be to use the add on's firebug and firepath for firefox much easier to locate elements using them.

Comment: I am using firepath and firebug. Firepath showed me that XPath when I click on that box. and also showing 1 matching node too when I search that XPath in a complete page.
Well, your given XPath works. Thank you so much.
I am trying to post complete HTML code in a comment but it giving me the error of character limit exceed. From help I got to know I need to use backtick but still, I am not able to post complete HTML. Anyways thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code. It works:-

```
 driver.navigate().to("http://uk.support.tomtom.com/app/questions  /extended_warranty");
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.findElement(By.id("rn_LoginFormRedirect_3_Username")).sendKeys("myemailaddress");
```